# Concatenating image path from Database in asp.net core

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I am trying to concatenate a base path of image folder with a complete path coming from a DB in a .cshtml file to show image on the page but nothing is working out in my end. The best solution that I have tried is,

```
 @foreach (var item in Model)
                {
                    string img = @"~/pics"+Html.DisplayFor(modelItem=>item.ImagePath);
                        <article>
                            @*My Dynamic Article*@
                            <div class="content">
                                <h3>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)</h3>
                                <img src="@img" width="95%" alt="Laser" />
                                <p>Hello</p>
                            </div>
                        </article>}
```

But this too is outputting something strange, I see this path in the output on web browser,

```
<img src="~/picsMicrosoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.StringHtmlContent" width="95%" alt="Laser" />
```

Tell me some method that works fine with asp.net core MVC latest release. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this problem, you can put the content of the `img` variable directly into the `src` attribute, and add the **@** symbol directly in front of `Html.DisplayFor(modelItem=>item.ImagePath)`.

Here is the work code:

```
                @foreach (var item in Model)
                { 
                        <article>
                            @*My Dynamic Article*@
                            <div class="content">
                                <h3>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)</h3>
                                <img src="~/pics/@Html.DisplayFor(model =>item.ImagePath)" width="95%" alt="Laser" />
                                <p>Hello</p>
                            </div>
                        </article>}
```

Or you can directly get ImagePath by following:

```
<img src="~/pics/@item.ImagePath" width="95%" alt="Laser" />
```

Here is the test result:

[image]